# Increase the font size of a NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to create an input text box where the user clicks (point is an NSPoint where the user clicked).

Right now I have it working, but the input box that's being displayed is too small.  I'd like to have it fill up the outer view (showed in blue).

```
    // Text Storage
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] init];
    [textStorage setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:18]];

    // Layout Manager
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    NSRect textViewBounds = NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, NSWidth(self.window.frame), 50);

    // Text Container
    NSTextContainer *textContainer;
    textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc]
                     initWithContainerSize:textViewBounds.size];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    // Text View
    NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewBounds];

    // Of course text editing should be as undoable as anything else.
    [textView setAllowsUndo:YES];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    //[textView setDrawsBackground:NO];

    [self addSubview:textView];

    // Make the editing view the first responder so it takes key events and relevant menu item commands.
    //[self.window setContentView:textView];
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:textView];
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText` which exposes the method:

```
- (void)setFont:(NSFont *)aFont
```

You should be able to set the font family and size via `NSFont` and it's various methods. If you just want to set the size, you can use:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont userFontOfSize:21.0];
```

To specify a font family and size, you can use:

```
+ (NSFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I haven't used `NSTextStorage` before. However, looking at the documentation, `NSTextStorage` also exposes the method `- (void)setFont:(NSFont *)font`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yep, I've tried it.  It's in the code above.  Strange that it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant have you tried `setFont:` on your `NSTextView` not on `NSTextStorage` as in your code above. Perhaps it's because `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSAttributedString` which has more complex mechanisms for setting text attributes.